# Error when I try to run App with GoogleMapApiv2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have problem to run simply app with GoogleMapsApiV2.

I did tutorial from this movie: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc 
and I have error's on 13:00 minutes, when trying to run app (the problem arises on Emulator and Galaxy S)

Log Cat Error's:  http://cpaste.eu/1398

Code's:

- AndroidManifest.xml: http://cpaste.eu/1401
- MainActivity.java: http://cpaste.eu/1400
- activity_main.xml: http://cpaste.eu/1402

Has anyone an idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your class should extend [`android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html), not its parent `android.app.Activity`. The telling line in the logs is:

> 07-09 21:12:54.634: E/AndroidRuntime(416): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader

Inheriting from `FragmentActivity` should correct this `Exception`.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are including and exporting `google-play-services.jar`

Comment: I have add library in app Properties -> Android -> Add library and select google-play-services_lib.

Errors: Console: http://cpaste.eu/1404
LogCat: http://cpaste.eu/1405. In console error's something about google-play-services.apk... not found